# Nuxt 3 problem with building the server for production: AUTH_NO_ORIGIN: No `origin

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

I build my project, and got this issue, when i try to run the server on my local pc. I'm using "@sidebase/core": "^0.1.4"

PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\dir\project> node .output/server/index.mjs
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/dir/project/.output/server/chunks/node-server.mjs:377
throw new Error(ERROR_MESSAGES.NO_ORIGIN);

Error: AUTH_NO_ORIGIN: No `origin` - this is an error in production, see https://sidebase.io/nuxt-auth/resources/errors. You can ignore this during development
at getServerOrigin (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/dir/project/.output/server/chunks/node-server.mjs:377:9)
at file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/dir/project/.output/server/chunks/node-server.mjs:400:5
at createNitroApp (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/dir/project/.output/server/chunks/node-server.mjs:988:5)
at file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/dir/project/.output/server/chunks/node-server.mjs:992:18
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

I tried to add AUTH_ORIGIN="http://localhost:3000/" in my .env file, also in [...].ts auth file, but it doesn't solve a problem

[...].ts

```html
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

// @ts-ignore
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
  // your authentication configuration here!
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  secret: 'secret',
  providers: [
    // @ts-expect-error You need to use .default here for it to work during SSR. May be fixed via Vite at some point
    CredentialsProvider.default({

      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'email', type: 'email' },
        password: { type: 'password', label: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize (credentials: any) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw createError({
            statusCode: 500,
            statusMessage: 'Missing Info'
          })
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        })

        if (!user || !user.password) {
          throw createError({
            statusCode: 401,
            statusMessage: 'Invalid Credentials'
          })
        }

        const correctPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password
        )
        if (!correctPassword) {
          throw createError({
            statusCode: 401,
            statusMessage: 'Invalid Credentials'
          })
        }
        return user
      }
    })

  ],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login'
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  }
})
```

nuxt.config.ts

```html
import { setAbsoluteSqliteDatabaseUrlForPrisma } from './prisma/utils'

setAbsoluteSqliteDatabaseUrlForPrisma()

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    version: '0.0.1',
    authSecret: '', // can be overridden by NUXT_AUTH_SECRET environment variable
    githubId: '',
    githubSecret: '',
    googleId: '',
    googleSecret: '',
    authOrigin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
  auth: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', '@sidebase/nuxt-auth', 'nuxt-svgo', '@huntersofbook/naive-ui-nuxt', 'vue3-carousel-nuxt', '@pinia/nuxt'],
  extends: ['@sidebase/core'],
  typescript: {
    shim: false
  },
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.css'
  ],
  pinia: {
    storesDirs: ['./stores/**']
  }
})
```

code snippets:
nuxt.config.ts

[...].ts

Maybe i need to do smth else, can you help?

[[...].ts img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvQLH.jpg) - img of [...].ts file

Comment: Could you please update your question with code snippets from the "[...].ts" and "nuxt.config.ts" files? That would add some helpful context.

Comment: Also, please let us know what version of Nuxt and @sidebase/nuxt-auth you are using, thanks.

Comment: i've uploaded it, you can check it out [...].ts img - img of [...].ts file

Comment: sent code snippets

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting this up with Nuxt (I'm assuming Nuxt 3 since you haven't specified), you'll want to set the env var `NUXT_AUTH_ORIGIN` rather than `AUTH_ORIGIN`.

You can find more notes about how Nuxt auto-sets properties in the `runtimeConfig` here in their docs: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config#environment-variables